# Access Denied in S3 Bucket

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

Please help I am facing the weired problem, I am trying to access S3 Bucket Image, I am able to list bucket items but when trying to render the image in web application using the pointed url I am getting the  **Access denied** error
. I am using cognito (Federated Identities).

Already set Trust RelationShip

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "us-east-1:"
        },
        "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "unauthenticated"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my full code

```
protected IAmazonEC2 ec2;
        protected IAmazonS3 s3;
        protected IAmazonSimpleDB sdb;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {


            CognitoAWSCredentials credentials = new CognitoAWSCredentials(
    "us-east-1:ox0d70gm-1922z-4772-b2132-9748c6548bdb", // Identity pool ID
    RegionEndpoint.USEast1);


            Console.WriteLine("Identity ID: " + credentials.GetCredentials().Token);
            Console.WriteLine("Identity ID: " + credentials.GetCredentials().UseToken);
            Console.WriteLine("Access Key Id" + credentials.GetCredentials().AccessKey);
            Console.WriteLine("Secret Key:" + credentials.GetCredentials().SecretKey);


            IAmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);

            try {

                ListBucketsResponse response = s3Client.ListBuckets();

                List<S3Bucket> lS3Bucket = response.Buckets;

                foreach (S3Bucket s3 in lS3Bucket) {
                    Console.WriteLine(s3.BucketName);

                    ListObjectsV2Request request = new ListObjectsV2Request {
                        BucketName = s3.BucketName
                    };

                    ListObjectsV2Response responseV2;

                    responseV2 = s3Client.ListObjectsV2(request);

                    foreach (S3Object entry in responseV2.S3Objects) {

                        if(s3.BucketName== "saveen-2017-june-15") {
                            Response.Write("<img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/"+ entry.BucketName + "/"+ entry.Key + "' height=100 width=100/>"); // access denied error
                        }
                    }
                }

                int numBuckets = 0;
                if (response.Buckets != null &&
                    response.Buckets.Count > 0) {
                    numBuckets = response.Buckets.Count;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("You have " + numBuckets + " Amazon S3 bucket(s).");
            } catch (AmazonS3Exception ex) {
                if (ex.ErrorCode != null && (ex.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidAccessKeyId") ||
                    ex.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidSecurity"))) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please check the provided AWS Credentials.");
                    Console.WriteLine("If you haven't signed up for Amazon S3, please visit http://aws.amazon.com/s3");
                } else {
                    Console.WriteLine("Caught Exception: " + ex.Message);
                    Console.WriteLine("Response Status Code: " + ex.StatusCode);
                    Console.WriteLine("Error Code: " + ex.ErrorCode);
                    Console.WriteLine("Request ID: " + ex.RequestId);
                }
            }
```

**UPDATED Section**

Further I have researched and found that I need to implement 
**Developer Authenticated Identities Authflow (Enhanced Authflow) In**

Steps are given below

1. Login via Developer Provider (code outside of Amazon Cognito)
2. Validate the user's login (code outside of Amazon Cognito)
3. GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity
4. GetCredentialsForIdentity

Below is the full code to implement above

```
class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {

        //GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity
        CognitoAWSCredentials credentials = new CognitoAWSCredentials(
                "us-east-1:#####-####-####-####-########", RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

        //GetCredentialsForIdentity
        GetCredentialsForIdentityResponse tokenResp = identityClient.GetCredentialsForIdentity(credentials.GetIdentityId());

        string date = GetRoute53Date();

        Console.WriteLine(GetAWSR53_SHA1AuthorizationValue(tokenResp.Credentials.GetCredentials().AccessKey, tokenResp.Credentials.GetCredentials().SecretKey, date));
        // Now here I have Access key and Signature

        Console.Read();
    }



    public static string GetAWSR53_SHA1AuthorizationValue(string AWSAccessKeyId,
        string AWSSecretAccessKey, string AmzDate) {
        System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1 MySigner =
           new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1(
           System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AWSSecretAccessKey));

        string SignatureValue = Convert.ToBase64String(
          MySigner.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AmzDate)));

        string AuthorizationValue = "AWS3-HTTPS AWSAccessKeyId=" +
           System.Uri.EscapeDataString(AWSAccessKeyId) +
           ",Algorithm=HmacSHA1,Signature=" + SignatureValue;

        return AuthorizationValue;
    }

    public static string GetRoute53Date() {
        string url = "https://route53.amazonaws.com/date";
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse response;
        response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        return response.Headers["Date"];
    }

}
```

Now I am accessing the S3 bucket Image resource and want to display.

I am using below code

```
GET /####-###-###-15/myfile.png HTTP/1.1
Host: s3.amazonaws.com
Authorization: AWS ASIAJ4DZFDVDEB3GSNDA:ulAQKnJkiLAWFg8cB+F+5hje0mE=
x-amz-date: Thu, 26 Apr 2018 07:14:18 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

It's giving me the error which is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidAccessKeyId</Code>
    <Message>The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.</Message>
    <AWSAccessKeyId>ASIAJ4DZFDVDEB3GSNDA</AWSAccessKeyId>
    <RequestId>C593C6DE5E004836</RequestId>
    <HostId>fS+WnzQo0UtqlUaLyoMfIxbKElRs56xYPcL8bNn62VQ41HLG26Mr2Aq+2UL6IsZvO1xFxp6lZdc=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: You got bucket policy on your bucket? If so, can you post it?

Comment: There is no policy has been added in bucket, means it is empty

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to use default amazon urls like `https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/image.jpg` (which seems to be the case), this is probably because by default they are not public from the outside.

You have to set your object to "public" before showing them in a web application I guess.

You can do it here in the console:
[image: Make object public in S3]

Once changed, then in the object property, you can directly access the web url:
[image: see here]

Otherwise, you will get the "access denied" error when trying to access that URL
[image: as here]

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**
Based on comments, then I would suggest you to have a look at "Pre-signed URLs". [more info](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html). I guess this is somehow what you are trying to achieve. Keeping the object privates in s3 while granting clients **temporary** GET/PUT access. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank for the effort you made, But in my case I want to make it private and want to access through Identity Pool access token...

Comment: Even though I haven't found any decent article about it in one place...

Comment: All right. I agree with you... Haven't found a decent one either. By the way check edits & happy coding! Hope it helps!